# How to transmit infrared by android phone for TV like power on or off?

Tags: java, android, infrared

```
 int[] power=    {123,339,23,54,23,14,23,16,21,14,21,16,21,14,23,16,21,16,21,14,23,53,23,15,22,16,21,54,23,14,23,16,21,16,21,54,23,54,23,53,23,54,23,14,23,54,23,14,23,54,22,54,23,16,21,16,21,14,23,14,23,16,21,16,21,54,23,54,23,15,22,15,22,14,23,14,23,14,23,14,23,53,23,54,23,14,23,14,23,16,21,54,23,14,23,16,21,14,23,16,21,14,23,16,21,14,23,53,23,53,23,54,23,54,23,2500};
ConsumerIrManager mCIR = (ConsumerIrManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);
    mCIR.transmit(47000, power);
```

I already declared in manifest. it's not crashing but i don't know whether it's transmitted or not.After that i do not know how to know what it's going to transmit and whether it's transmit or not.so please tell me whether this is right code or not or how i check code is properly working or not by programming.
thanks in advance.

Comment: i used 4.4+ version of android..

Comment: does your device have an IR blaster? if not, then there is NOTHING you can do to make this work.

Comment: yes.. i checked before transmitting..

Comment: why people are give negative vote . if any mistake you people tell then if you give -ve i accept and learn something but people are telling nothing and gave -ve..

Comment: when i checked in intex lcd tv it's not working but when we click on button then light is emerging.is there any dependency for particular company tv.@Marc B

Comment: when i used this code and i want to power on for intex tv then it's not working. from phone ir emmiting i shaw light burned.but tv not on.is there any dependecy for intex or other company tv.@Marc B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
power.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            irSend(v);
        }
    });

    volup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            irSend(v);
        }
    });

    voldown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            irSend(v);
        }
    });
    irData = new SparseArray<String>();
        irData.put(R.id.voldown,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0003 00a9 00a8 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0040 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0702 00a9 00a8 0015 0015 0015 0e6e"));
        irData.put(R.id.volup,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0003 00a9 00a8 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0702 00a9 00a8 0015 0015 0015 0e6e"));
        irData.put(R.id.power,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0003 00a9 00a8 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0702 00a9 00a8 0015 0015 0015 0e6e"));



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        irInit4KitKat();

    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void irInit4KitKat() {

    // Get a reference to the ConsumerIrManager
    mCIR = (ConsumerIrManager) getSystemService(Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);

}


public void irSend(View view) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){

        irSend4Kitkat(view);
         }
      }

       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
       private void irSend4Kitkat(View view) {

      if(mCIR.hasIrEmitter() == true){
         String data = irData.get(view.getId());
        if (data != null) {
        String values[] = data.split(",");
        int[] pattern = new int[values.length-1];

        for (int i=0; i<pattern.length; i++){
           pattern[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i+1]);
       }
       Log.e("LOG", mCIR.getCarrierFrequencies()+ "@" +        Integer.parseInt(values[0]) + "@" + pattern);

      mCIR.transmit(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), pattern);
       }
     }else{
           Log.e("LOG", "not supported options");
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "This device is not Support     infrared." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }



protected String hex2dec(String irData) {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(irData
    .split(" ")));
list.remove(0); // dummy
int frequency = Integer.parseInt(list.remove(0), 16); // frequency
list.remove(0); // seq1
list.remove(0); // seq2

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
list.set(i, Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(list.get(i), 16)*26));
}

frequency = (int) (1000000 / (frequency * 0.241246));
    list.add(0, Integer.toString(frequency));

irData = "";
for (String s : list) {
irData += s + ",";
}
return irData;
 }
}
```

> I also set the permission in menifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR"
android:required="false" />
```